# How can my backfill job find out how much time the scheduler has allocated to it?

Tags: slurm

I have an application that takes a command line argument telling it how much time it has been allocated.  The application then checkpoints itself at a convenient point and exits before the specified amount of time.

I'm launching jobs with

```
sbatch --time=240 --time-min=60
```

How within my `run.sub` file can I find out how much time the scheduler has allocated to my job?  I assumed there would be an environment variable to tell me the time allocation, much like `$SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES` tells me how many nodes I've been allocated, but I haven't been able to find such a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is legal to invoke `squeue` from inside the `run.sub` file, and this allows to discover additional information about the currently running job.  So

`squeue -j ${SLURM_JOBID} --noheader --Format=TimeLimit`

returns the time remaining in days-hours:minutes:seconds format and

`squeue -j ${SLURM_JOBID} --noheader --Format=EndTime`

returns the absolute end time in something similar to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.